# Sharing a fabfile across multiple projects

Tags: deployment, workflow, dry, fabric, pip

[Fabric](http://fabfile.org) has become my deployment tool of choice both for deploying [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) projects and for initially configuring Ubuntu [slices](http://www.slicehost.com). However, my current workflow with [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) isn't very [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself), as I find myself:

1. copying the `fabfile.py` from one [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) project to another and
2. modifying the `fabfile.py` as needed for each project (e.g., changing the `webserver_restart` task from Apache to Nginx, configuring the host and SSH port, etc.).

One advantage of this workflow is that the `fabfile.py` becomes part of my [Git](http://git-scm.com/) repository, so between the `fabfile.py` and the [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) `requirements.txt`, I have a recreateable [virtualenv](http://bitbucket.org/ianb/virtualenv/overview/) and deployment process. I want to keep this advantage, while becoming more [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself). It seems that I could improve my workflow by:

1. being able to `pip install` the common tasks defined in the `fabfile.py` and
2. having a `fab_config` file containing the host configuration information for each project and overriding any tasks as needed

Any recommendations on how to increase the [DRY](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself)ness of my [Fabric](http://fabfile.org) workflow?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some work in this direction with class-based "server definitions" that include connection info and can override methods to do specific tasks in a different way. Then my stock fabfile.py (which never changes) just calls the right method on the server definition object.